# SQL - Find unused lookup values for each parent

Tags: sql

Say I have a table called Ingredient containing 5 different pizza toppings.

```
1. Ham
2. Pineapple
3. Banana
4. Chocolate
5. Tomato
```

And then I have a Pizza table and a PizzaTopping table (linking to Ingredient).  Those two tables describe pizza's that have been made and sold.

---

Now for each pizza, I want to show all of the ingredients that weren't used for each of the pizza's I sold.  For example, if Pizza 1 was Ham, Pineaple and Banana (i.e. Ingredients 4 and 5 weren't used) and Pizza 2 was Pinepple, Chocolate and Tomato (e.g. Ingredients 1 and 3 weren't used), I'd see this:

```
Pizza    Ingredient
1           4
1           5
2           1
2           3
```

I want this to be a view, so I can't use sub-queries...

Comment: Note: you can use subqueries in a View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join all your pizzas with all the ingredients, then filter the ones actually used with a `NOT EXISTS`.

```
SELECT
    P.Pizza,
    I.Ingredient
FROM
    Pizza P
    CROSS JOIN Ingredient I
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'ingredient not used' FROM PizzaTopping T WHERE T.Pizza = P.Pizza AND I.Ingredient = T.Ingredient)
```

---

**EDIT**: For SQL Server indexed view:

```
SELECT
    P.Pizza,
    I.Ingredient
FROM
    Pizza P
    CROSS JOIN Ingredient I
    LEFT JOIN PizzaTopping T ON 
        T.Pizza = P.Pizza AND 
        I.Ingredient = T.Ingredient
WHERE
    T.Pizza IS NULL
```

Comment: That works perfectly, which is great and I might be able to use it as-is, but note that primarily, I couldn't use a subquery because I needed this to be an indexed view.

Comment: @JamesD edited. You forgot to mention that you needed an **indexed** view!